# Required field validator not working in updatepanel progress bar

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

> I used updatepanel to show progress bar...and from the time i used it my validations for the textbox is not working....

```
<div class="login">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="updatepanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>

                <h1>SELECT DATE</h1><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" CssClass="login-inp" title="Enter Date" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" ValidationGroup="cdr"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" SetFocusOnError="false"  Display="None" ValidationGroup="cdr" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter Date"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server">
                </asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
                <asp:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" 
                    Format="yyyy-MM-dd" runat="server" >
                </asp:CalendarExtender>

                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" Text="DOWNLOAD AND VIEW CDR" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" OnClientClick="StartProgressBar()" ValidationGroup="cdr" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnexport" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" style="display:none;"  OnClick="btnexport_Click" ValidationGroup="cdr" /><!--Hidden button  --><br /><br />
                <div class="grid">

                    <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" CssClass="Grid" BackColor="LightGoldenrodYellow"
                    BorderColor="Tan" BorderWidth="5px" CellPadding="3" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="None"
                    BorderStyle="None" CellSpacing="2" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"
                    Width="50%"  ApplyFormatInEditMode="True" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging"   >
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="Tan" />
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="DarkSlateBlue" ForeColor="GhostWhite" />
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign = "Right" CssClass = "GridPager" />

                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="Tan" Font-Bold="True"  />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="PaleGoldenrod" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                </div>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <%--<Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnexport" />
        </Triggers>--%>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Style="display: none; background-color: #C0C0C0;">
    <img src="loader.gif" alt="" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenField" runat="server" />
    </asp:Panel>            
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ProgressBarModalPopupExtender" runat="server"
    BackgroundCssClass="ModalBackground" behaviorID="ProgressBarModalPopupExtender"
     TargetControlID="hiddenField" PopupControlID="Panel1">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>         
    <%--<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="updatepanel1">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="overlay">
            <div style=" z-index:-100; margin-left: 95px;margin-top:-170px;opacity: 1;-moz-opacity: 1;">
                img alt="" src="loader.gif" style="width: 100px; height: 100px" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>--%>
</div>
```

I tried keeping 1)updatemode=conditional
                 2)validation group
                and many other fixes...but nothing worked out...

Comment: Can you remove, OnClientClick="StartProgressBar()" from button and try again?

Comment: @Piyush Khatri   Brother...i tried your way but now progress bar pop up is not visible...while downloading...and for OnClientClick="StartProgressBar()...i had this javascript function with that name to show progress bar pop up extender.

Comment: Yes, it was just for testing. Is validator works correct?

Comment: @Piyush Khatri ...yes validators were working perfectly fine earlier...

Comment: Post your javascript function here, StartProgressBar().

Comment: @Piyush Khatri     <script type="text/javascript">

    function StartProgressBar() {
        var myExtender = $find('ProgressBarModalPopupExtender');
        myExtender.show();
        return true;
    }
                           </script>